Program crashes valgrind only in Qt Creator
I'm writing a C++ program with several threads, lots of IO, etc. and I want to check for memory leaks.  The program runs great in debug build, and release build.  But, if I run Valgrind from within Qt Creator (v 12.0.2) with Qt5.15.2, I see some output from my program and then:
21:18:04: Analyzing finished.
21:18:04: Process exited with return value Process crashed
21:18:04: Analyzing finished.

But there is no output showing where it crashed!  I tried running valgrind on my program from the bash command prompt and it runs fine (though LOTS of output because of no supression files for Qt).  No crash.
There's something about running Valgrind in Qt Creator that exposes a memory problem (I'm guessing).  But I can't find it!  I have core (crash) files enabled, yet my program crashing does not cause a core dump to be written.  I'm at a loss...how do I find out what's going on to cause the crash?

Can you post source code that reproduces the issue?

No, If I could post a MRE then I would know where the bug is.  I'm trying to find the offending code.

Generally ‘LOTS of output’ isn’t due to a lack of suppression files. It’s due to errors. Can you post the first few errors?

Running Valgrind in Qt Creator should make almost no difference compared to standalone in a shell. There may be some extra environment variables and the standard file descriptors are probably redirected. I’m not sure if Creator uses vgdb so that you can stop and examine values as errors occur. You can do that from one or two shells as well.

I discovered the cause (and it extends a solution I discovered long ago).  Qt can use self modifying code (SMC) when performing QRegularExpression or QRegEx operations.
SMC can crash valgrind, which is why I always enable the smc-check=all option in Projects>Run>Valgrind Settings>Valgrind Generic Settings.  If you expand that box there is an option for WHERE to check for SMC, which by default is only on stack.
It turns out I started to make my QRegularExpressions static (recommended by Qt since they are resource intensive), which moved them to the heap.  Once I changed the above option to "Everywhere" valgrind was happy again.
I'm not sure what the command line equivalent is, but outside of Qt Creator valgrind ran fine with only the --smc-check=all option.  But inside Qt Creator the SMC seemed to steer pointers into problem areas that caused valgrind to crash.

It’s a bit of a problem that it isn’t obvious as to which arguments are being used. That’s often the case with GUIs that are doing things under the hood. Do you have a Valgrind rc file or use the VALGRIND_OPTS environment variable? Creator could be overriding them. Can you see the log file from the Creator runs or is that hidden?

There's a stdout window that shows how valgrind is run from Qt Creator.  I tried using the exact same args from bash command prompt and all ran fine.  So just load order from Qt Creator was enough to tip the balance.  I can't see the vlagrind output when run from Qt Creator - all piped back into Qt Creator.
